Why attendence Context fetching again on navigation back to the teacherattend component?
I need to use attendance data often on my website, So I make it as utility as below:
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useCallback,
  createContext
} from 'react';
import { sendJSONRequest,getRequest } from '../utility/sendJson';

const AttendenceContext = createContext()

const AttendenceProvider = ({
  children,
  type,
  grade = "",
  setGrade = ""
}) => {
  console.log("AttendenceProvider rendered, type:", type);
  const [list, setList] = useState([])
  const [attendence, setAttendence] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    if (type === "Teacher") {
      let teacherData = await getRequest(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/getTeacher"
      );
      teacherData = Object.values(teacherData.data).flat();
      let attendData = await sendJSONRequest(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/getAttendence",
        { type: type }
      );
      attendData = Object.values(attendData.data).flat() 
      processData(teacherData, attendData)
    } else if (type === "Student") {}
  }, [type])

  const processData = async(data, attendenceData) => {
    setAttendence(attendenceData)
    const newData = data.map((teacher) => {
      const check = attendenceData.some((attendence) => {
        return attendence.attendeId === teacher._id;
      })
        ? "Absent"
        : "Present";

      return {
        name: teacher.name,
        attendeId: teacher._id,
        status: check,
      };
    }, []);
    await setList(newData);
    await setLoading(false)
  }

  const updateGrade = (newGrade) => {
    setGrade(newGrade);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [fetchData]);

  const Data = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      list,
      attendence,
      updateGrade
    }
  }, [list, attendence])

  return (
    <AttendenceContext.Provider value={Data}>
      {!loading ? children : <div>Loading....</div>}
    </AttendenceContext.Provider>
  )
}

export { AttendenceContext, AttendenceProvider };

I'm using it in TeacherAttend component as below:
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useCallback,
  useRef,
  useContext
} from 'react';
import { Attendance } from '../../layoutattendance';
import { sendJSONRequest, getRequest } from '../../../utility/sendJson';
import { AttendenceContext } from '../../../utility/AttendenceContext';

const Teacherattend = React.memo(() => {
  const { list, attendence } = useContext(AttendenceContext);

  const [teacherList, setTeacherList] = useState(list)
  const [AttendenceData, setAttendenceData] = useState(attendence)

  const handleStatus = (attendeId) => {
    const newTeacher = teacherList.map(data => {
      if (data.attendeId === attendeId) {
        return {
          ...data,
          name: data.name,
          attendeId: attendeId , 
          status: data.status === "Present" ? "Absent" : "Present"
        }  
      } else return data
    })
    setTeacherList(newTeacher)
  }

  const handleCilck = async () => {
    if (teacherList.length === 0) {
      console.log("No Teachers to Mark Attendance");
      return;
    }

    const data = {
      teacher: teacherList.map(({ name , ...rest }) => rest),
      attendence: AttendenceData
    }

    try {
      let newAttendence = await sendJSONRequest(
        "http://localhost:5000/portal/mark/attendence",
        data
      );
      console.log(newAttendence)
      if (
        newAttendence.data.deleted &&
        newAttendence.data.deleted.length !== 0
      ) {
        setAttendenceData((perv) => {
          return perv.filter(person => {
            return !newAttendence.data.deleted.includes(
              person.attendeId
            )
          })
        })
      }
      if (
        newAttendence.data.added &&
        newAttendence.data.added.length !== 0
      ) {
        setAttendenceData(perv => [
          ...perv,
          ...newAttendence.data.added
        ])
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="py-6 px-2 lg:px-4 bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg">
      {list || list.length !== 0
        ? <Attendance
            name="Teacher Attendance"
            data={teacherList}
            onStatusChange={handleStatus}
          />
        : "Loading.."
      }
      <div className="flex justify-end mt-6">
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={handleCilck}
          className="motion-preset-shrink  py-3 px-6 text-lg font-semibold text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 rounded-lg shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500 transition duration-300"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}); 

export default Teacherattend;

The following is my main.jsx:
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import Get from "./components/Account/GetStarted.jsx";
import Admin from "./components/Admin/Admin.jsx";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import AdminTeachers from "./components/Admin/components/teachers.jsx";
import Students from "./components/Admin/components/students.jsx";
import Teachers from "./components/Teacher/teachers.jsx";
import Attendance from "./components/Teacher/components/attendance";
import Addstudent from "./components/Admin/components/studentsinfo.jsx"
import Teachersattend from "./components/Admin/components/Teacherattend.jsx"
import Removestudent from "./components/Admin/components/removestudent.jsx"
import Addteacher from "./components/Admin/components/addTeacher.jsx"
import ClassesLists from "./components/Headmaster/components/ClassesLists.jsx";
import Home from './components/Teacher/components/home.jsx'
import PrivateRoute from "./utility/PrivateRoute.jsx";
import { AuthProvider } from "./utility/AuthContext.jsx";
import Class from "./components/Admin/components/class.jsx";
import View from "./components/Admin/components/view.jsx";
import Substitution from "./components/Admin/components/Substitution.jsx";
import Classadd from "./components/Admin/components/classadd.jsx";
import Manage from "./components/Admin/components/manage.jsx";
import Time from "./components/Admin/components/time.jsx";
import {AttendenceProvider} from "./utility/AttendenceContext.jsx";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  // Public Routes
  { path: "/", element: <App /> },
  { path: "/login", element: <Get /> },
  // Headmaster Routes
  {
    path: "/headmaster",
    element: (
      <PrivateRoute roles={["headmaster"]}>
        <Home />
      </PrivateRoute>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "students",
        element: (
          <PrivateRoute roles={["headmaster"]}>
            <ClassesLists />
          </PrivateRoute>
        ),
      },
    ],
  },
  // Admin Routes
  {
    path: "/admin",
    element: (
      <PrivateRoute roles={["Admin"]}>
        <Admin />
      </PrivateRoute>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "", // Important: Empty string for index route
        element: (
          <AttendenceProvider type="Teacher">
            <Teachersattend />
          </AttendenceProvider>
        ),
      },
      { path: "teachers", element:<AdminTeachers />},
      { path: "students", element:<Students /> },
      { path: "students/add", element: <Addstudent />},
      { path: "teachers/add", element: <Addteacher />},
      { path: "students/remove", element:<Removestudent />},
      { path: "class", element:<Class />},
      { path: "class/view", element:<View />},
      { path: "class/add", element:<Classadd />},
      { path: "teachers/substitution", element:<Substitution />},
      { path: "teachers/manage", element:<Manage />},
      { path: "time", element:<Time />},
    ],
  },
  // Teacher Routes
  {
    path: "/teachers",
    element: (
      <PrivateRoute roles={["Teacher"]}>
        <Teachers />
      </PrivateRoute>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/teachers",
        element: (
          <PrivateRoute roles={["Teacher"]}>
            <Home />
          </PrivateRoute>
        ),
      },
      {
        path: "/teachers/attendance",
        element: (
          <PrivateRoute roles={["Teacher"]}>
            <Attendance />
          </PrivateRoute>
        ),
      },
    ],
  },
  // Unauthorized Route
  { path: "/unauthorized", element: <div>Unauthorized Access</div> },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AuthProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);

I also tested my auth provider but I didn't find any problem.
My Authcontext:
import React, {
  createContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useCallback,
  useMemo,
  useContext
} from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext(null);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    roles: [],
    loading: true,
  });

  const fetchAuth = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/portal/auth", {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = await response.json();

        if (
          !auth.isAuthenticated ||
          !arraysAreEqual(auth.roles, data.role)
        ) {
          setAuth({
            isAuthenticated: true,
            roles: data.role,
            loading: false,
          });
        }
      } else {
        // Efficient check before setting state
        if (auth.isAuthenticated || !auth.loading) {
          setAuth({ isAuthenticated: false, roles: [], loading: false }); 
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching auth data:", error);
      // Efficient check before setting state
      if (auth.isAuthenticated || !auth.loading) {
        setAuth({ isAuthenticated: false, roles: [], loading: false });
      }
    }
  }, [auth]); 

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAuth();
  }, [fetchAuth]);

  const login = useCallback((userData) => {
    setAuth({ isAuthenticated: true, roles: userData.role });
  }, []); // Empty dependency array

  const logout = useCallback(() => {
    setAuth({ isAuthenticated: false, roles: [], loading: false }); 
  }, []);

  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({
    auth,
    login,
    logout,
  }), [auth, login, logout]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {!auth.loading ? children : <div>Loading...</div>}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Helper function for shallow comparison of arrays
function arraysAreEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  if (!arr1 || !arr2 || arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false; 
  // Handle null/undefined
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider");
  }
  return context;
};
export { AuthContext, AuthProvider, useAuth };

I don't want to refetch, when I renavigate to the component. But After my debugging, now it's fetching more than two times. But why?

What are the exact reproduction steps here? Am I understanding correctly you navigate to "/admin" and the AttendenceProvider component renders and fetches data, and then you navigate somewhere else and then back to "/admin" and the AttendenceProvider mounts again and fetches data again? If so then this would appear to be correct behavior given the code you have shared. Please [edit] to clarify what the exact specific problem is that you are trying to resolve.

Yes, You are right. But I do not want to fetch data again when I navigate back to /admin. How can I implement it in this way?

When/how often does the fetched data change and need to be re-fetched? Does it just need to be fetched only once ever for each app instance for that specific route?

Now, It almost fetches six times when I land on /the admin route. It should be fetched once the user hits the /admin route for the first time.

Now, I have solved the issue. I just moved the AttendanceProvider to the admin component not to the teacher attend component. This resolved my issue.


It should be fetched once the user hits the /admin route for the first time.

You are using AttendanceProvider as a wrapper component and rendering on the specific "/admin" route. Each time that route is matched the element component is mounted and runs the initial effects, e.g. fetching data, and when you navigate off that route, the element component is unmounted. Navigating back to "/admin" will mount AttendanceProvider and fetch the data again.
I suggest pushing the AttendanceProvider higher up the ReactTree so that it is mounted only once, and provides the fetched data and the callback to fetch it. The descendant component can check if the data has been loaded already and fetch if it has not been loaded. Or the callback function can be a bit smarter and only fetch the data if it hasn't already been fetched/loaded.
import React, {
  useContext,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
  useCallback,
  createContext
} from 'react';
import { sendJSONRequest, getRequest } from '../utility/sendJson';

const AttendanceContext = createContext({
  attendance: null,
  fetchData: () => {},
  isLoading: false,
  list: null,
  updateGrade: () => {},
});

export const useAttendance = () => useContext(AttendanceContext);

export const AttendanceProvider = ({
  children,
  grade = "",
  setGrade = () => {},
}) => {
  // Data is initially null
  const [list, setList] = useState(null);
  const [attendance, setAttendance] = useState(null);

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async (type) => {
    // If data fetched already, return early
    if (list !== null && attendance !== null) return;

    const processData = (data, attendanceData) => {
      setAttendance(attendanceData);
      setList(data.map((teacher) => ({
        name: teacher.name,
        attendeId: teacher._id,
        status: attendanceData.some(
          ({ attendeId }) => attendeId === teacher._id
        )
          ? "Absent"
          : "Present",
      }));
    };

    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      switch(type) {
        case "Teacher":
          const flattenResponseData = ({ data }) => Object.values(data).flat();
          const [teacherData, attendData] = await Promise.all([
            getRequest("http://localhost:5000/api/getTeacher")
              .then(flattenResponseData),
            sendJSONRequest(
              "http://localhost:5000/api/getAttendance",
              { type }
            )
              .then(flattenResponseData),
          ]);
          processData(teacherData, attendData);
          break;

        case "Student":
        default:
          // nothing
      }
    } catch(error) {
      // set the states to empty arrays after "loading" + error
      setAttendance([]);
      setList([]);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [processData]);    
    
  const value = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      attendance,
      fetchData,
      isLoading,
      list,
      updateGrade: setGrade
    }
  }, [attendance, fetchData, isLoading, list, setGrade]);
      
  return (
    <AttendanceContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </AttendanceContext.Provider>
  );
}

Create a wrapper to call the fetchData callback provided by the AttendanceProvider component.
import { useAttendance } from '../../../utility/AttendanceContext';

export const AttendanceWrapper = ({ children, type }) => {
  const { fetchData, isLoading } = useAttendance();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(type);
  }, [fetchData, type]);

  return isLoading ? <div>Loading....</div> : children;
};

Wrap TeachersAttend with the new AttendanceWrapper component and render AttendanceProvider higher in the ReactTree around the router.
// Admin Routes
{
  path: "/admin",
  element: (
    <PrivateRoute roles={["Admin"]}>
      <Admin />
    </PrivateRoute>
  ),
  children: [
    {
      index: true,
      element: (
        <AttendanceWrapper type="Teacher">
          <TeacherAttend />
        </AttendanceWrapper>
      ),
    },
    ...
  ],
},

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <AttendanceProvider>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </AttendanceProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  </StrictMode>
);

const TeacherAttend = () => {
  const { attendance, list } = useAttendance();
  ...
};

